# Hibernate - Simple data but complex sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I need to make a hql/sql query using Hibernate but I don't know exactly how can I achieve that in Hibernate. Backend database is SQL Server.

I have transactional table with master statuses - Pending, Deposit, Clear & Bounce.

**Transactions - Table 1**

```
Seq    Receipt ID     Status
1       1234         Pending
2       2345         Deposited
3       3456         Cleared
4       4567         Bounced
```

Initially the records are in `Pending`. Movement of records is `from Pending to Deposit` and then `from Deposit to either Cleared or Bounced`. Depending on the status change to either `Cleared` or `Bounced` it inserts data in another table - `Table 2`

Current hql query that is working fine simply reads the data from `Table 1` and look for the same status in `Table 2` for particular receipt ID. Something like below

```
Select receiptID from Table1 where table1.status in ('Bounced','Cleared') 
and not exists (select table2.receiptID from Table2 where 
table1.receiptID = table2.receiptID and table2.status in ('Cleared','Bounced'))
```

This works good so far, as at any point of time there will be 1 record of either `Cleared or Bounced` in Table2.

**New Change**

Now the change required is to enter the record for `Deposit` as well in `Table2`. So, when status changes from `Pending to Deposit`, I need to enter data in `Table2`.

Now obviously, just by adding status as `Deposit` in above query won't work. As it will work fine for `Deposit`, but when status will change from `Deposit to Cleared/Bounced`, then system will find existing record in `Table2` (sub-query) for `Deposit` hence it won't enter any new record for `Cleared or Bounced`. :(

I think I can do this with union, but not sure how do I achieve it in Hibernate (HQL) without any complex query.

Help plz!!!

Answer (score 0):

After much of a thinking, yes am able to find a solution. I just have to add another not exists condition specific for Deposit of Table1 and Clear of Table2.

New Query looks like

```
Select receiptID from Table1 where table1.status in ('Deposit','Bounced','Cleared') 
        and not exists ( select table2.receiptID from Table2 
                            where table1.receiptID = table2.receiptID 
                            and   table2.status in ('Cleared','Bounced')
                            and   table1.status = table2.status )
        and not exists (select table2.receiptID from Table2
                            where table1.receiptID = table2.receiptID 
                            and   table1.status in ('Deposit'
                            and   table2.status in ('Cleared') )
```